# What is the intended purpose of the Hex Branch instruction on the IBM System/32

Tags: ibm-midrange, retro-computing

Does anyone know the intended use of the Hex Branch instruction on the IBM System/32?

In case there is a clever reader who doesn't know the System/32, Hex Branch substitutes the high nybble of the low byte of the Micro-instruction Address Register (MAR, the program counter) with a 4-bit immediate value in the instruction. It then substitutes the low nybble of the low byte of the instruction address register with either the zone or numeric portion of a either the high or low byte of a register.

From SY31-0346-4 5320 Theory Diagrams, Fifth Edition (May 1977)

> This instruction operates as a 16 way unconditional branch. Either the zone or digit portion of either the high or low byte of the selected register is used to replace bits 12-15 of MAR. Bits 8-11 of
> MAR are replaced by the bit settings of MAR'.

(MAR' is 4 bits taken from the instruction. Note that IBM labels bits left to right, so 01234567.)

From the description, it would appear that this instruction is intended to be used with zoned decimal values. In a zoned decimal value, the low nybble of a byte contains a numeric value 0-9, the high nybble of the one's position represents the sign of the multi-digit decimal number. There are multiple values for both positive and negative, but the preferred values are 0b1111, for positive, and 0b1101, for negative. The zone value of the digits in other than the one's position is not considered.

Because this is an absolute jump, it seems that the programmer would need to know the address of the instruction to know where the branch is going to resume, but perhaps that's handled by the assembler.

As an example, suppose MAR contains 0x1234, and WR2 contains 0xF5D6 (-56). After

```
HBZ 7,WR2(L)
```

MAR would contain 0x127D.

What would be the point of that? How would you know what instruction was at that address?

Comment: It's an intriguing question, but any answers are likely to be speculation, which makes it a poor fit for Stack Overflow. I do wish you luck in finding an answer, though. It seems to me that if anyone can provide a guess as to how it _could_ be useful, there is a good chance that it is one of, if not the only, intended purpose of the instruction.

Comment: Might it be used to generate a crude jump table relative to the current location in the program? In your case it would jump to x127D for a negative number in the register, or x127F for a positive number. Most assembly language programmers are intimately familiar with where instructions are in memory, especially within a 256 byte page of memory.

Comment: @John-Y Thanks for taking the time to comment. Are you saying that because you believe no one who ever programmed the System/32 frequents Stackoverflow that I shouldn't have asked the question at all, or are you saying that I should have left off the part beginning with "In case there is a clever reader" and just kept the first part?

Comment: @tim.smith - Thank you for taking the time to try to understand my comment. First, I do not have any belief one way or the other about whether a System/32 programmer would see this question. I just think that a *definitive* answer would require citing some reference to back it up, and *that's* what I doubt (but would not categorically rule out) the existence of. You're asking for the rationale behind a design, and only the designer or someone closely involved with the design would know that.

Comment: That being said, I think that *given* you've already asked the question, the fact that you've provided some material for people to consider is a good thing, in terms of increasing the likelihood that you get a useful answer (regardless of whether the original question is a good fit for this site, and regardless of the authoritativeness of the answer).

Comment: The comment by @jmarkmurphy seems to be responding to "How would you know what instruction was at that address?" with "why *wouldn't* you know what instruction was at that address?". That was actually my initial reaction too, but I don't have any real experience with that level of programming.

Answer (score 1):

These System/32 instructions in the Theory of Operations manual are for the "CSP" - the Control Storage Processor.   In effect, they are the actual instructions used to write the "microcode" that was then used to interpretively execute the user-visible S/32 instruction set of the "MSP" - the Main Storage Procesor, that was the same as the IBM System/3, and what was used by the IBM RPG-II and COBOL compilers; MSP and CSP was also used on the S/34 and S/36 processors -- the CSP side ran the SSP operating system, and the MSP ran the user's COBOL or RPG-II applications.  (Note that S/34 and S/36 FORTRAN and BASIC actually ran with the "scientific instructions" that ran with different microcode loaded on the CSP.)

If you examine all of the IBM manuals available for S/3, S/32, S/34, and S/36 on Bitsavers, you can get a better idea ... the S/34 and S/36 assembler language manuals and "Scientific Instructions" manuals are there, too.   Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That much I was able to find. Bitsavers is a great resource. I wrote a System/3 emulator using those reference, and I thought I'd try the 32 as my next project.